# Android MediaPlayer not playing sound on some devices

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have made a simple alert beep for my application. But the problem is that the sound is played on some devices and in some others not.

**The sample code below:**

```
public void audioPlayer() { // leshon tingull kur ka kolision //Armando 8/7/2013
        MediaPlayer beep_alert = MediaPlayer.create(Maps.this,R.raw.double_beep);
        try {
            beep_alert.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

There is no error shown, it just don play for example `nexus 4`, but it plays ok in `nexus 7`.

What is going wrong?

The double_beep is a mp3 file.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How did you test it? Did you plug two different phones in and use as dev. phones?

Comment: Forgive me if this is obvious but have you checked the volume for the stream (usually STREAM_MUSIC) is up so the sound is audible on the Nexus 4?

Comment: The volume for the apps were down... What a shame for me now... Is there any way to increase the volume from the code? In this way i force the system to play the sound?

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the volume is up, otherwise you won't hear anything.

Generally it's not really advised to turn the volume up programmatically without any user input - if the volume is down it's usually through user action in the first place.

But here's how you can do it:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
```

This will max out `STREAM_MUSIC`. There are many other ways to control/change volume.

Have a read through this as well to familiarise yourself with controlling volumes: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html

Answer (score 0):

Your sound file shoudn't contain Special characters like `_` (Underscore) and all. Try it by renaming into `doubledeep`. Also it should not starts with `Capital Letter`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast reply. I tried renaming the file without Underscore but it don't plays again in nexus 4.

Comment: Did you check your Volume? When it plays on one device, it will play in other device too. Re-install the app once again if the problem continues.

Comment: The volume for the apps were down. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @OlsiSaqe Cool down :) If this answer is useful, then vote up and accept this answer. Because it will help others who comes to view this problem! Thanks!

Comment: *Your sound file shoudn't contain Special characters like _ (Underscore) and all.* what's so wrong with an underscore?