# Android AudioPlayer volume extremly low

Tags: java, android, audio, android-activity

I am doing a little trivia game that plays a correct or wrong song when the user chooses an answer. This is my function:

```
public void playSound(boolean isRight) {

    if(isRight){

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.correct);
        mp.setVolume(VOLUME,VOLUME);
        mp.start();

    }else{

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.wrong);
        mp.setVolume(VOLUME,VOLUME);
        mp.start();

    }


}
```

My problem is that even though my audio is properly played, it has an extremly low volume on my device(which has maximun volume).

I already tried many solutions found here on Stackoverflow but the only one that seems to work is this: [Android MediaPlayer not playing sound on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620112/android-mediaplayer-not-playing-sound-on-some-devices) but it doesnt respect the user's volume.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of VOLUME?

Comment: It is `public static final float VOLUME = 1.0f;`

Comment: can you post one of the audio files? Maybe they are mixed with a really low volume.